# Use Keras TimeseriesGenerator function to generate squence Group By some ID

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I need to use TimeseriesGenerator to feed data into a LSTM network. Situation is that, the sequences generated by TimeseriesGenerator function needs to consider the values only within the IDs. For eg, consider the following data:

```
dt = pd.DataFrame({'ids':[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3], 'values':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7]})
```

For sequence length is 3, I need following output:

```
[[[1., 1.], [1., 2.], [1., 3.]]
,[[1., 2.], [1., 3.], [1., 4.]]
,[[1., 3.], [1., 4.], [1., 5.]]
,[[1., 4.], [1., 5.], [1., 6.]]
,[[1., 5.], [1., 6.], [1., 7.]]
,[[2., 1.], [2., 2.], [2., 3.]]
,[[2., 2.], [2., 3.], [2., 4.]]
 ...
 ]
```

However, when I run the below:

```
X = TimeseriesGenerator(dt.values,dt.values,3,batch_size = dt.shape[0])
```

I get 2 additional undesired elements as below before the sequence for ID = 2 starts:

```
[[1., 6.], [1., 7.],[2., 1.]],[[1., 7.],[2., 1.],[2., 2.]]
```

I know that looping through all IDs is a solution, but that takes massive time when I am doing it in real life, Is there any shortcut to achieve that?

Comment: In fact, `TimeseriesGenerator` source code also uses loop to get data. If you want to save time,you need to rewrite your own `TimeseriesGenerator` class. Other methods can only reduce code without saving time.

Comment: Seems that the source at github is not full. It has only a pass statement

Comment: You can refer `TimeseriesGenerator` source code in here https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/sequence.py.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to write custom data generator. Below code should fit your custom *ids* based batch generation which you can use as a  baseline and coustomize it as as required.

```
import keras
import numpy as np
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
    def __init__(self, dt, length, batch_size=128):
        self.tgs = list()
        for i in range(dt['ids'].min(),dt['ids'].max()+1):
            adf = dt[dt['ids'] == i]
            self.tgs.append(TimeseriesGenerator(adf.values,adf.values,length,batch_size =batch_size))
        self.len = sum([len(tg) for tg in self.tgs])
        self.idx_i = list()
        self.idx_j = list()

        for i, tg in enumerate(self.tgs):
            self.idx_i.extend(list(range(len(tg))))
            self.idx_j.extend([i]*len(tg))    
        #print ( self.idx_i,  self.idx_j)

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.tgs[self.idx_j[index]][self.idx_i[index]]

# Test
g = DataGenerator(dt,3,3)
for i in range(len(g)):
    print (g[i])
```

- I am creating a generator for each id and storing it in `tgs`
- The no:of batches are the sum of batches in each generator
- `idx_j` maps a index to corresponding generator
- `idx_i` maps a index to a batch in the the generator mapped by `idx_j`

Output:

```
(array([[[1., 1.], [1., 2.], [1., 3.]],
        [[1., 2.], [1., 3.], [1., 4.]],
        [[1., 3.], [1., 4.], [1., 5.]]]), 
        array([[1., 4.], [1., 5.], [1., 6.]]))
(array([[[2., 1.], [2., 2.], [2., 3.]],
       [[2., 2.], [2., 3.], [2., 4.]],
       [[2., 3.], [2., 4.], [2., 5.]]]), 
       array([[2., 4.], [2., 5.], [2., 6.]]))
(array([[[3., 1.], [3., 2.],[3., 3.]],
       [[3., 2.], [3., 3.], [3., 4.]],
       [[3., 3.], [3., 4.], [3., 5.]]]), 
       array([[3., 4.], [3., 5.], [3., 6.]]))
```